# Aggregating multiple object arrays and sum their properties up

Tags: javascript, arrays, charts, aggregate

I'm looking for the best performing method to solve the following task: Given is some array as the one below, which contains monthly data. I already use the *Array.filter()* method beforehand, so this example is already reduced to two months. For readability, I have used a JSON beautifier.

```
var dbSource = [
   {
      "t":"2016-10-01T00:00:00",
      "c":968,
      "d":[
         {
            "eka1":1,
            "anz1":22,
            "kos1":4400,
            "tag1":"1E"
         },
         {
            "eka1":1,
            "anz1":1,
            "kos1":200,
            "tag1":"1K"
         },
         {
            "eka1":1,
            "anz1":12,
            "kos1":2400,
            "tag1":"1N"
         },
         {
            "eka1":1,
            "anz1":41,
            "kos1":8200,
            "tag1":"1R"
         },
         {
            "eka2":0.6364,
            "anz2":11,
            "kos2":1600,
            "tag2":"2A"
         },
         {
            "eka2":1,
            "anz2":6,
            "kos2":1200,
            "tag2":"2D"
         },
         {
            "eka2":1,
            "anz2":2,
            "kos2":400,
            "tag2":"2E"
         },
         {
            "eka2":0.1839,
            "anz2":87,
            "kos2":6750,
            "tag2":"2F"
         },
         {
            "eka2":0.1613,
            "anz2":31,
            "kos2":2300,
            "tag2":"2G"
         },
         {
            "eka2":0.6724,
            "anz2":58,
            "kos2":8750,
            "tag2":"2K"
         },
         {
            "eka2":1,
            "anz2":1,
            "kos2":200,
            "tag2":"2L"
         },
         {
            "eka2":1,
            "anz2":3,
            "kos2":600,
            "tag2":"2Q"
         },
         {
            "eka2":1,
            "anz2":181,
            "kos2":36200,
            "tag2":"2R"
         },
         {
            "eka2":1,
            "anz2":1,
            "kos2":200,
            "tag2":"2S"
         },
         {
            "eka2":1,
            "anz2":2,
            "kos2":400,
            "tag2":"2U"
         },
         {
            "eka2":1,
            "anz2":2,
            "kos2":400,
            "tag2":"2V"
         },
         {
            "eka2":0.0312,
            "anz2":64,
            "kos2":3500,
            "tag2":"2Z"
         },
         {
            "eka4":1,
            "anz4":10,
            "kos4":2000,
            "tag4":"4K"
         },
         {
            "eka4":1,
            "anz4":25,
            "kos4":5000,
            "tag4":"4R"
         },
         {
            "eka4":0.85,
            "anz4":40,
            "kos4":7100,
            "tag4":"4U"
         },
         {
            "eka5":1,
            "anz5":16,
            "kos5":3200,
            "tag5":"5A"
         },
         {
            "eka5":0.875,
            "anz5":8,
            "kos5":1450,
            "tag5":"5B"
         },
         {
            "eka5":1,
            "anz5":1,
            "kos5":200,
            "tag5":"5C"
         },
         {
            "eka5":0.3333,
            "anz5":3,
            "kos5":300,
            "tag5":"5D"
         },
         {
            "eka5":0,
            "anz5":1,
            "kos5":50,
            "tag5":"5F"
         },
         {
            "eka5":0.5,
            "anz5":6,
            "kos5":750,
            "tag5":"5G"
         },
         {
            "eka5":1,
            "anz5":33,
            "kos5":6600,
            "tag5":"5K"
         },
         {
            "eka5":0.5,
            "anz5":2,
            "kos5":250,
            "tag5":"5R"
         },
         {
            "eka5":0.5,
            "anz5":4,
            "kos5":500,
            "tag5":"5S"
         },
         {
            "eka5":0.5,
            "anz5":8,
            "kos5":1000,
            "tag5":"5W"
         },
         {
            "eka6":1,
            "anz6":5,
            "kos6":1000,
            "tag6":"6A"
         },
         {
            "eka6":0,
            "anz6":1,
            "kos6":50,
            "tag6":"6B"
         },
         {
            "eka6":1,
            "anz6":1,
            "kos6":200,
            "tag6":"6P"
         },
         {
            "eka6":1,
            "anz6":1,
            "kos6":200,
            "tag6":"6U"
         },
         {
            "eka9":1,
            "anz9":4,
            "kos9":800,
            "tag9":"9 "
         },
         {
            "ekaB":0.8605,
            "anzB":43,
            "kosB":7700,
            "tagB":"BF"
         },
         {
            "ekaG":1,
            "anzG":2,
            "kosG":400,
            "tagG":"GF"
         },
         {
            "ekaG":1,
            "anzG":1,
            "kosG":200,
            "tagG":"GT"
         },
         {
            "ekaG":0,
            "anzG":1,
            "kosG":50,
            "tagG":"GU"
         },
         {
            "ekaM":0.9592,
            "anzM":49,
            "kosM":9500,
            "tagM":"MS"
         },
         {
            "ekaO":0.95,
            "anzO":80,
            "kosO":15400,
            "tagO":"OD"
         },
         {
            "ekaO":1,
            "anzO":5,
            "kosO":1000,
            "tagO":"OE"
         },
         {
            "ekaO":1,
            "anzO":7,
            "kosO":1400,
            "tagO":"OL"
         },
         {
            "ekaO":1,
            "anzO":11,
            "kosO":2200,
            "tagO":"OM"
         },
         {
            "ekaO":1,
            "anzO":16,
            "kosO":3200,
            "tagO":"OP"
         },
         {
            "ekaO":1,
            "anzO":46,
            "kosO":9200,
            "tagO":"OR"
         },
         {
            "ekaO":1,
            "anzO":1,
            "kosO":200,
            "tagO":"OV"
         },
         {
            "ekaT":1,
            "anzT":12,
            "kosT":2400,
            "tagT":"T "
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "t":"2016-09-01T00:00:00",
      "c":1542,
      "d":[
         {
            "eka1":1,
            "anz1":25,
            "kos1":5000,
            "tag1":"1E"
         },
         {
            "eka1":1,
            "anz1":4,
            "kos1":800,
            "tag1":"1F"
         },
         {
            "eka1":1,
            "anz1":7,
            "kos1":1400,
            "tag1":"1K"
         },
         {
            "eka1":1,
            "anz1":27,
            "kos1":5400,
            "tag1":"1N"
         },
         {
            "eka1":1,
            "anz1":33,
            "kos1":6600,
            "tag1":"1R"
         },
         {
            "eka2":0.8095,
            "anz2":21,
            "kos2":3600,
            "tag2":"2A"
         },
         {
            "eka2":1,
            "anz2":4,
            "kos2":800,
            "tag2":"2D"
         },
         {
            "eka2":0.6,
            "anz2":5,
            "kos2":700,
            "tag2":"2E"
         },
         {
            "eka2":0.1333,
            "anz2":75,
            "kos2":5250,
            "tag2":"2F"
         },
         {
            "eka2":0.4302,
            "anz2":86,
            "kos2":9850,
            "tag2":"2G"
         },
         {
            "eka2":0.7703,
            "anz2":74,
            "kos2":12250,
            "tag2":"2K"
         },
         {
            "eka2":1,
            "anz2":7,
            "kos2":1400,
            "tag2":"2L"
         },
         {
            "eka2":1,
            "anz2":1,
            "kos2":200,
            "tag2":"2Q"
         },
         {
            "eka2":1,
            "anz2":322,
            "kos2":64400,
            "tag2":"2R"
         },
         {
            "eka2":1,
            "anz2":3,
            "kos2":600,
            "tag2":"2U"
         },
         {
            "eka2":1,
            "anz2":7,
            "kos2":1400,
            "tag2":"2V"
         },
         {
            "eka2":0.0345,
            "anz2":58,
            "kos2":3200,
            "tag2":"2Z"
         },
         {
            "eka4":1,
            "anz4":3,
            "kos4":600,
            "tag4":"4A"
         },
         {
            "eka4":1,
            "anz4":1,
            "kos4":200,
            "tag4":"4F"
         },
         {
            "eka4":1,
            "anz4":1,
            "kos4":200,
            "tag4":"4H"
         },
         {
            "eka4":1,
            "anz4":28,
            "kos4":5600,
            "tag4":"4K"
         },
         {
            "eka4":1,
            "anz4":44,
            "kos4":8800,
            "tag4":"4R"
         },
         {
            "eka4":0.6667,
            "anz4":45,
            "kos4":6750,
            "tag4":"4U"
         },
         {
            "eka5":1,
            "anz5":29,
            "kos5":5800,
            "tag5":"5A"
         },
         {
            "eka5":1,
            "anz5":6,
            "kos5":1200,
            "tag5":"5B"
         },
         {
            "eka5":0.5,
            "anz5":2,
            "kos5":250,
            "tag5":"5C"
         },
         {
            "eka5":1,
            "anz5":2,
            "kos5":400,
            "tag5":"5D"
         },
         {
            "eka5":0.6667,
            "anz5":6,
            "kos5":900,
            "tag5":"5F"
         },
         {
            "eka5":0.6,
            "anz5":10,
            "kos5":1400,
            "tag5":"5G"
         },
         {
            "eka5":1,
            "anz5":61,
            "kos5":12200,
            "tag5":"5K"
         },
         {
            "eka5":1,
            "anz5":1,
            "kos5":200,
            "tag5":"5R"
         },
         {
            "eka5":0.8571,
            "anz5":7,
            "kos5":1250,
            "tag5":"5S"
         },
         {
            "eka5":1,
            "anz5":1,
            "kos5":200,
            "tag5":"5W"
         },
         {
            "eka6":1,
            "anz6":5,
            "kos6":1000,
            "tag6":"6A"
         },
         {
            "eka6":1,
            "anz6":2,
            "kos6":400,
            "tag6":"6B"
         },
         {
            "eka6":1,
            "anz6":1,
            "kos6":200,
            "tag6":"6P"
         },
         {
            "eka6":1,
            "anz6":1,
            "kos6":200,
            "tag6":"6U"
         },
         {
            "eka9":1,
            "anz9":1,
            "kos9":200,
            "tag9":"9 "
         },
         {
            "ekaB":0.9412,
            "anzB":119,
            "kosB":22750,
            "tagB":"BF"
         },
         {
            "ekaG":1,
            "anzG":4,
            "kosG":800,
            "tagG":"GF"
         },
         {
            "ekaG":1,
            "anzG":1,
            "kosG":200,
            "tagG":"GP"
         },
         {
            "ekaG":0,
            "anzG":1,
            "kosG":50,
            "tagG":"GU"
         },
         {
            "ekaM":0.9891,
            "anzM":92,
            "kosM":18250,
            "tagM":"MS"
         },
         {
            "ekaO":0.9732,
            "anzO":112,
            "kosO":21950,
            "tagO":"OD"
         },
         {
            "ekaO":1,
            "anzO":9,
            "kosO":1800,
            "tagO":"OE"
         },
         {
            "ekaO":1,
            "anzO":12,
            "kosO":2400,
            "tagO":"OL"
         },
         {
            "ekaO":1,
            "anzO":22,
            "kosO":4400,
            "tagO":"OM"
         },
         {
            "ekaO":1,
            "anzO":27,
            "kosO":5400,
            "tagO":"OP"
         },
         {
            "ekaO":1,
            "anzO":111,
            "kosO":22200,
            "tagO":"OR"
         },
         {
            "ekaO":1,
            "anzO":5,
            "kosO":1000,
            "tagO":"OV"
         },
         {
            "ekaT":1,
            "anzT":11,
            "kosT":2200,
            "tagT":"T "
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

The array consists of any number of identical objects with a timestamp *t* (first day of the month), a total count of entries *c*, as well as a data array *d*. The data array always contains four properties, *ekaX* (percentage), *anzX* (count), *kosX* (decimal value) and *tagX* (string value; group name), while X can be a arbitrary alphanumeric character (which is always identical to the first char of *tagX*).

For a chart, I need to aggregate these values. This means, that *anzX* and *kosX* should be summed up, the resulting *ekaX* should be a weighted average with *anzX* as weight, and *tagX* should remain as group name. Objects with different *tagX* values mustn't be aggregated. The result should be a single *d* type object.

I researched for quite some time, but I haven't found a simple way yet. Array.reduce() seems to be an appropriate method, but I don't know, if and how I can use it in such a complex context.

I would be really thankful, if a more advanced JavaScript developer could help me out. My focus is more on vb.net, so I'm pretty new to JavaScript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to calculate new data from objects in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39897018/how-to-calculate-new-data-from-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: please add a kind of expected result.

Comment: @Lucero While it looks similar at the first glance, I don't want to add values up by various filter conditions, like in the thread you mentioned. I basically want to merge and aggregate multiple arrays into one.

Comment: I know that they are not *identical* but I thought that it could serve as a good starting point for aggregating array data in JS. Look at the profile of @NinaScholz - she has more related answers posted here on SO.

Comment: @NinaScholz Like this:

 result = [
  {
   "eka1":1,
   "anz1":47,
   "kos1":9400,
   "tag1":"1E"
  },
  {
   "eka1":1,
   "anz1":4,
   "kos1":800,
   "tag1":"1F"
  },
  {
   "eka1":1,
   "anz1":8,
   "kos1":1600,
   "tag1":"1K"
  },
  {
   "eka1":1,
   "anz1":39,
   "kos1":7800,
   "tag1":"1N"
  },
  {
   "eka1":1,
   "anz1":68,
   "kos1":14800,
   "tag1":"1R"
  },
  {
   "eka2":0.749996875,
   "anz2":32,
   "kos2":5200,
   "tag2":"2A"
  },
  …
 ]

Comment: @WhiteHat I'm using DevExpress' DevExtreme web chart suite. [link](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/#demo/charts-line_and_point_series-bubble)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collect all values and build new objects with a hash table.

```js
var dbSource = [{ t: "2016-10-01T00:00:00", c: 968, d: [{ eka1: 1, anz1: 22, kos1: 4400, tag1: "1E" }, { eka1: 1, anz1: 1, kos1: 200, tag1: "1K" }, { eka1: 1, anz1: 12, kos1: 2400, tag1: "1N" }, { eka1: 1, anz1: 41, kos1: 8200, tag1: "1R" }, { eka2: 0.6364, anz2: 11, kos2: 1600, tag2: "2A" }, { eka2: 1, anz2: 6, kos2: 1200, tag2: "2D" }, { eka2: 1, anz2: 2, kos2: 400, tag2: "2E" }, { eka2: 0.1839, anz2: 87, kos2: 6750, tag2: "2F" }, { eka2: 0.1613, anz2: 31, kos2: 2300, tag2: "2G" }, { eka2: 0.6724, anz2: 58, kos2: 8750, tag2: "2K" }, { eka2: 1, anz2: 1, kos2: 200, tag2: "2L" }, { eka2: 1, anz2: 3, kos2: 600, tag2: "2Q" }, { eka2: 1, anz2: 181, kos2: 36200, tag2: "2R" }, { eka2: 1, anz2: 1, kos2: 200, tag2: "2S" }, { eka2: 1, anz2: 2, kos2: 400, tag2: "2U" }, { eka2: 1, anz2: 2, kos2: 400, tag2: "2V" }, { eka2: 0.0312, anz2: 64, kos2: 3500, tag2: "2Z" }, { eka4: 1, anz4: 10, kos4: 2000, tag4: "4K" }, { eka4: 1, anz4: 25, kos4: 5000, tag4: "4R" }, { eka4: 0.85, anz4: 40, kos4: 7100, tag4: "4U" }, { eka5: 1, anz5: 16, kos5: 3200, tag5: "5A" }, { eka5: 0.875, anz5: 8, kos5: 1450, tag5: "5B" }, { eka5: 1, anz5: 1, kos5: 200, tag5: "5C" }, { eka5: 0.3333, anz5: 3, kos5: 300, tag5: "5D" }, { eka5: 0, anz5: 1, kos5: 50, tag5: "5F" }, { eka5: 0.5, anz5: 6, kos5: 750, tag5: "5G" }, { eka5: 1, anz5: 33, kos5: 6600, tag5: "5K" }, { eka5: 0.5, anz5: 2, kos5: 250, tag5: "5R" }, { eka5: 0.5, anz5: 4, kos5: 500, tag5: "5S" }, { eka5: 0.5, anz5: 8, kos5: 1000, tag5: "5W" }, { eka6: 1, anz6: 5, kos6: 1000, tag6: "6A" }, { eka6: 0, anz6: 1, kos6: 50, tag6: "6B" }, { eka6: 1, anz6: 1, kos6: 200, tag6: "6P" }, { eka6: 1, anz6: 1, kos6: 200, tag6: "6U" }, { eka9: 1, anz9: 4, kos9: 800, tag9: "9 " }, { ekaB: 0.8605, anzB: 43, kosB: 7700, tagB: "BF" }, { ekaG: 1, anzG: 2, kosG: 400, tagG: "GF" }, { ekaG: 1, anzG: 1, kosG: 200, tagG: "GT" }, { ekaG: 0, anzG: 1, kosG: 50, tagG: "GU" }, { ekaM: 0.9592, anzM: 49, kosM: 9500, tagM: "MS" }, { ekaO: 0.95, anzO: 80, kosO: 15400, tagO: "OD" }, { ekaO: 1, anzO: 5, kosO: 1000, tagO: "OE" }, { ekaO: 1, anzO: 7, kosO: 1400, tagO: "OL" }, { ekaO: 1, anzO: 11, kosO: 2200, tagO: "OM" }, { ekaO: 1, anzO: 16, kosO: 3200, tagO: "OP" }, { ekaO: 1, anzO: 46, kosO: 9200, tagO: "OR" }, { ekaO: 1, anzO: 1, kosO: 200, tagO: "OV" }, { ekaT: 1, anzT: 12, kosT: 2400, tagT: "T " }] }, { t: "2016-09-01T00:00:00", c: 1542, d: [{ eka1: 1, anz1: 25, kos1: 5000, tag1: "1E" }, { eka1: 1, anz1: 4, kos1: 800, tag1: "1F" }, { eka1: 1, anz1: 7, kos1: 1400, tag1: "1K" }, { eka1: 1, anz1: 27, kos1: 5400, tag1: "1N" }, { eka1: 1, anz1: 33, kos1: 6600, tag1: "1R" }, { eka2: 0.8095, anz2: 21, kos2: 3600, tag2: "2A" }, { eka2: 1, anz2: 4, kos2: 800, tag2: "2D" }, { eka2: 0.6, anz2: 5, kos2: 700, tag2: "2E" }, { eka2: 0.1333, anz2: 75, kos2: 5250, tag2: "2F" }, { eka2: 0.4302, anz2: 86, kos2: 9850, tag2: "2G" }, { eka2: 0.7703, anz2: 74, kos2: 12250, tag2: "2K" }, { eka2: 1, anz2: 7, kos2: 1400, tag2: "2L" }, { eka2: 1, anz2: 1, kos2: 200, tag2: "2Q" }, { eka2: 1, anz2: 322, kos2: 64400, tag2: "2R" }, { eka2: 1, anz2: 3, kos2: 600, tag2: "2U" }, { eka2: 1, anz2: 7, kos2: 1400, tag2: "2V" }, { eka2: 0.0345, anz2: 58, kos2: 3200, tag2: "2Z" }, { eka4: 1, anz4: 3, kos4: 600, tag4: "4A" }, { eka4: 1, anz4: 1, kos4: 200, tag4: "4F" }, { eka4: 1, anz4: 1, kos4: 200, tag4: "4H" }, { eka4: 1, anz4: 28, kos4: 5600, tag4: "4K" }, { eka4: 1, anz4: 44, kos4: 8800, tag4: "4R" }, { eka4: 0.6667, anz4: 45, kos4: 6750, tag4: "4U" }, { eka5: 1, anz5: 29, kos5: 5800, tag5: "5A" }, { eka5: 1, anz5: 6, kos5: 1200, tag5: "5B" }, { eka5: 0.5, anz5: 2, kos5: 250, tag5: "5C" }, { eka5: 1, anz5: 2, kos5: 400, tag5: "5D" }, { eka5: 0.6667, anz5: 6, kos5: 900, tag5: "5F" }, { eka5: 0.6, anz5: 10, kos5: 1400, tag5: "5G" }, { eka5: 1, anz5: 61, kos5: 12200, tag5: "5K" }, { eka5: 1, anz5: 1, kos5: 200, tag5: "5R" }, { eka5: 0.8571, anz5: 7, kos5: 1250, tag5: "5S" }, { eka5: 1, anz5: 1, kos5: 200, tag5: "5W" }, { eka6: 1, anz6: 5, kos6: 1000, tag6: "6A" }, { eka6: 1, anz6: 2, kos6: 400, tag6: "6B" }, { eka6: 1, anz6: 1, kos6: 200, tag6: "6P" }, { eka6: 1, anz6: 1, kos6: 200, tag6: "6U" }, { eka9: 1, anz9: 1, kos9: 200, tag9: "9 " }, { ekaB: 0.9412, anzB: 119, kosB: 22750, tagB: "BF" }, { ekaG: 1, anzG: 4, kosG: 800, tagG: "GF" }, { ekaG: 1, anzG: 1, kosG: 200, tagG: "GP" }, { ekaG: 0, anzG: 1, kosG: 50, tagG: "GU" }, { ekaM: 0.9891, anzM: 92, kosM: 18250, tagM: "MS" }, { ekaO: 0.9732, anzO: 112, kosO: 21950, tagO: "OD" }, { ekaO: 1, anzO: 9, kosO: 1800, tagO: "OE" }, { ekaO: 1, anzO: 12, kosO: 2400, tagO: "OL" }, { ekaO: 1, anzO: 22, kosO: 4400, tagO: "OM" }, { ekaO: 1, anzO: 27, kosO: 5400, tagO: "OP" }, { ekaO: 1, anzO: 111, kosO: 22200, tagO: "OR" }, { ekaO: 1, anzO: 5, kosO: 1000, tagO: "OV" }, { ekaT: 1, anzT: 11, kosT: 2200, tagT: "T " }] }],
    grouped = Object.create(null),
    result = [];

dbSource.forEach(function (a) {
    a.d.forEach(function (b) {
        var x = Object.keys(b)[0].slice(-1),
            key = b['tag' + x];

        if (!grouped[key]) {
            grouped[key] = {};
            grouped[key]['kos' + x] = 0;
            grouped[key]['anz' + x] = 0;
            grouped[key]['eka' + x] = 0;
            grouped[key]['tag' + x] = key;
            result.push(grouped[key]);
        }
        grouped[key]['eka' + x] = (grouped[key]['eka' + x] * grouped[key]['anz' + x] + b['eka' + x] * b['anz' + x]) / (grouped[key]['anz' + x] + b['anz' + x]);
        grouped[key]['kos' + x] += b['kos' + x];
        grouped[key]['anz' + x] += b['anz' + x];

    });
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I was looking for! It works like a charm – and very fast.

Comment: By the way, your code for the weighted average incorrect. I already fixed it in my code. It should be `grouped[key]['eka' + x] = (grouped[key]['eka' + x] * grouped[key]['anz' + x] + b['eka' + x] * b['anz' + x]) / (grouped[key]['anz' + x] + b['anz' + x]);`, and you have to call it before adding up anzX.

Comment: I would love to do that, but whenever I try to edit your code, it always tells me that the code isn't formatted properly. Even if I don't change anything.

Comment: i change the order and made the change. is the result now right?

Comment: Thank you! That's it! :)